# Develop jenkins groovy script in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, groovy, ide, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to develop a groovy script (pipeline) for Jenkins in Eclipse? 
I want to connect to a running Jenkins instance and create / start some jobs. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I'm little late to the party. How about this: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jenkins-editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jenkins does not have strong IDE support in any IDE. However, Eclipse (as well as most major java IDE's) does have a groovy plugin and you can import the core jenkins jars to get some auto-completion. At the very least, the IDE gives you autoformatting, with is of some help. Once you've developed your script, you will have to copy it out to jenkins to test.

Comment: do you've any documentation which will help to achieve this. I'm very new to Jenkins hence asking.

Answer (score 1):

To work with [Jenkins Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), I have setup Eclipse like this:

1. Download and extract Jenkins.war Distribution (it's just a zip file with *.war file extension) from [jenkins.io](https://www.jenkins.io/download/), currently version 2.361.1 LTS.
2. Run the jenkins war file.

   - 2.1. Open a terminal and run `java -jar jenkins.war`.You will see that Jenkins will ask for the initial configuration and it will provide an initial password.
   - 2.2. Copy the initial password showed in the terminal.
   - 2.3 Open http://localhost:8080 in a WebBrowser and paste the initial password you have copied from the terminal.
   - 2.4. Follow the steps to install the default plugins. All of these files will be saved in `$HOME/.jenkins` folder.
3. Install [Eclipse Java IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) Version 2022-03 (4.23.0), I chose flavor: "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"
4. Install Eclipse [Groovy Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovy-development-tools) 4.5.0 (via Help->Marketplace search for groovy)
5. Create an Eclipse User Library via `Window` -> `Preferences`:

   Then go to `Java` -> `Build Path` -> `User Libraries`, add new User Library with name "Jenkins Pipeline". Then add the following "External Jars..." to this library.

   Uncompress jenkins.war (`tar xvf jenkins.war`) file and add the following files:

   - 5.1. `jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`
     Add these libraries from the plugins directory of jenkins home:
   - 5.2. `~/.jenkins/plugins/workflow-cps-global-lib/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`

     If you cannot find this directory it means you are running a new version of Jenkins. In this case, you should use:
     `~/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-groovy-lib/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`
   - 5.3. `~/.jenkins/plugins/workflow-cps/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`
   - 5.4. I also add junit to the library because it is often used:

     `~/.jenkins/plugins/junit/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`
6. Create your groovy pipeline project:

   `File` -> `New` -> `Project`... -> `Groovy` -> `Groovy Project`.

   Then add the User Library "Jenkins Pipeline" to the Build Path:

   Right click the groovy project -> `Build Path` -> `Add Libraries` -> `User Library`
7. Finally add more libraries from the plugins folder to your project according to your needs